# Ubercart vs Drupal commerce for french ecommerce site

Tags: commerce, ubercart

This is my first experience with french e-commerce site . I want to know which solution will speed up the developing of the website .

Also is there a module payment for Carte bleu  in drupal commerce, and is it ready for production site ?

Answer (score 2):

Check this [article](http://www.markroyko.com/blog/2011/12/14/ubercart-3-vs-drupal-commerce) which compares Ubercart & Commerce modules. Winner is commerce module for most advanced features and simplicity.

Commerce module is written from scratch to solve usability and other issues in Ubercart. Commerce module will be obvious choice for E-commerce portal.

As far as i know there is no out of the box module for Carte bleau payment gateway. But, if you know the module development you can write one and contribute to community using commerce payment gateway API. [This](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/utilizing-core-apis/writing-payment-method-module) will help you.

Best of luck :-)

Comment: @sel_space & Anil: (just fyi) Both the modules were written by Commerce guys. And according to them Drupal commerce is easy in long terms.

Answer (score 2):

For a fast solution D7 with Drupal commerce. Install a demo to see, Drupal commerce provide a version of Drupal7 with all modules necessary already installed. Add some items and you can use your e-commerce site few minutes after the install.

Now what'll take you times is the theming of your site. For that Ubercart can be better because of his background much more bigger than Drupal commerce.